# Align navigation buttons on all devices

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

As you can see on the picture, the bar on the bottom is using 5 different buttons (the icons). When I run my program with an iPhone 5s everything works fine. But on other devices such as the iPhone X, etc., the images floats to the left side. Does anyone know how I can add constraints to the buttons to make them stay where they are on all devices?

UPDATE: 
So, if you see the navigation-bar from the iPhone 5s, you see it's like "perfect" aligned to each other. And that's how I want them to be on ALL devices. If you take a look on the iPhone XS you can see that all the buttons is to the left. I also added "Flexible Space Bar Button Item" between all of the buttons, and it was a lot better, but they "Doghead" is not in the center of the phone, which I want.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Show your code how you constraint the buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a UIBarButtonItem with a system type of `.flexibleSpace` between each of your other buttons. This will force all of the buttons to be equally spaced across the width of the toolbar. To ensure that the middle button ends up in the center of the toolbar, all of the images need to be same width.

If you want all of the buttons grouped together in the center of the toolbar, then just add a flexible spaced item before the first button and another after the last button.

Comment: All images are the same size, but its still floating a bit to the left. :s

Comment: But your comment solved my issue, but I just dunno how I should fix the next step. Hehe